# Multiple types of users

Tags: django, django-models

I am writing a django web app that models an application where hospital staff and patients can login. The patients, nurses, and doctors all have different permissions and the models need to store different information. I am currently trying to create a user profile model that holds all the common fields, and then create separate models for each type of employee that each have a oneToOneField(UserProfile) attribute. I was wondering how I could tell which type of user was logged in from my views.py file. For example, is it possible to do something like:

```
    if request.user.is_patient():
        show patient form
    elif request.user.is_doctor:
        show doctor form
```

Here is what I have in models.py so far:

```
class BaseUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middleName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)

User.profile = property(lambda u: BaseUser.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

class PatientUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(BaseUser)
    existingConditions = models.TextField()
    prescriptions = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you have created a custom `BaseUser` model, you could set up a set of *properties* in that class to identify it.

This is a rough example that you could use to test in the view the nature of the user:

```
class BaseUser(models.Model):
    def is_patient(self):
        try:
            self.patientuser
        except PatientUser.DoesNotExist:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def is_doctor(self):
        try:
            self.doctoruser
        except DoctorUser.DoesNotExist:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Then, in your view, you could simply:

```
if request.user.baseuser.is_doctor():
    show doctor form
elif request.user.baseuser.is_patient():
    show patient form
```

To ensure that your users have a baseuser associated, you can take a look at the [post-save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) for the `User` model. You can check how to register actions for these signals [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals).

Here is a very simple example on how to do this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs): 
    BaseUser.objects.create(user=sender, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out.

Comment: I tried using your this suggestion but I get the exception user has no baseuser> any idea why this is?

Comment: Does your use have a baseuser instance associated?

Comment: BaseUser has a one to one association with User. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes,  but does your current user have a baseuser? What is the name of the exception?

Comment: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /accounts/edit   User has no baseuser

Comment: Excellent. That means you have to create the Baseuser for this user.  Try adding it in the admin

Comment: Thank, that worked. Is there a way to add a baseuser to a user when it is created instead of adding it through the admin console?

Comment: Take a look at django signals for model creation,  sorry I can't access the link from here

Comment: Hey @Stalfurion I updated the answer with the use of signals, want to take a look at it?

Comment: That's alright, I figured out how to use signals to add it. Thanks for the all the help